# How to add a ContentView to a Click Event?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

My assignment is to create a program that displays two buttons and my name and current time/date on the main screen. The goal is to have a passage appear once one of the buttons are pressed that will make use of the entire screen. So far, I have created the main page with the labels and buttons. However, I am very lost as to how to display the passage with respect to the button clicked. I am using the empirically fitting text way to make the best use of the screen. I have created a FontCalc.Cs page and added onContentViewSizeChanged method in the mainpage where I have all my code. I don't know how to proceed next. So far, this is what I have in my click handler event:

```
        passage1Button.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            passage.Text = "So they began working together, each squadron leader commanding indivual pilots, " +
                           "Ender comanding the squadron leaders. They learned manyw ays of working together, " +
                           "as the simulator forced them to try different situations. Sometimes the simulator " +
                           "gave them a larger fleet to work with; Ender set them up then in three or four " +
                           "toons that consisted of three or four squadrons each. Sometimes the simulator gave " +
                           "them a single starship with its twelve fighters, and he chose three sqaudron leaders. ";

            ContentView contentView = new ContentView
            {
                Content = passage
            };
            contentView.SizeChanged += onContentViewSizeChanged;
```

Instead of displaying the passage while having the buttons go away, it only freezes both the android emulator and the UWP local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a modal on button click

```
        passage1Button.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
         {
            var contentpage = new ShowTextPage("Passage text here, goes to page constructor where label is set to passed text");

            var page = new NavigationPage(contentpage);

            Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
         }
```

On the ShowTextPage, set HasNavigationBar to false

Comment: I am getting an error message when I hover over contentpage in the new NavigationPage line. It says cannot convert  from 'Lab12.ShowTextPage' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Comment: I currently have three files. One is called FontCalc.cs, the MainPage.xaml.cs file, and the one I just created with your code. Would you be able to look at the entirety of my code? If not, I understand. I managed to fix the error, but when I run it and click on the button my emulator freezes.

Comment: If you can post the code to those we can try to troubleshoot

Comment: Here is the complete assignment: 
You application will allow the user to display one of two passages from your favorite book (or movie). The passages displayed must efficiently use the screen (what we learned in chapter 4) to display the text.
The user will click a button to display a passage. Thus, there must be two buttons displayed when the application starts. The current date and time will also be displayed on the main screen. Your name will also be displayed on the main screen.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions